# Change image when div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div act like button that contain an image. I want when I click the div the image inside it will change I put a jquery but my jquery only work in 1 way it can switch to second image but cant switch back to first image.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="post-like m-30">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/like.png" alt="">
    <h4 class="bold text-center capital">appreciate this!</h4>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.post-like{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.post-like img{
    margin: auto;
}
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.post-like').click(function(){
       $(".post-like img").attr('src',"img/like.jpg");
       return false;
    });
});
```

Can you teach me why my jquery didnt work?

Comment: Your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/QAz2U/1329/.

Comment: lmao , why it not work in my pc. sorry fix that but how to make it switch back again?

Comment: Check your browser developper tools console.

Comment: already update my question sir. big pardon

Comment: You want to toggle between the both imgs on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To toggle between the both `src` attributes, you could add condition in your click event :

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.post-like').click(function(){
    var src = $(".post-like img").attr('src');

    if(src=="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/MRT_Singapore_Destination_1.png")
      $(".post-like img").attr('src',"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/MRT_Singapore_Destination_2.png");
    else
      $(".post-like img").attr('src',"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/MRT_Singapore_Destination_1.png");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-like m-30">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/MRT_Singapore_Destination_1.png" alt="">
  <h4 class="bold text-center capital">appreciate this!</h4>
</div><!-- post-like -->
```

Comment: I think toggle is all you need why make longer if/else statement when you can just call it in ``toggle``?

Comment: how to make toggle? sorry i know it dumb question. but im still learning

Comment: No @Riskbreaker it not all you need you're using two images when the OP use just one `img`. you have two answer the OP and not do it like you want, and we're toggling `src` attribute and not visibility of `img` element. and what will happen if we have another `img` tag? then you'll get another behavior.

Comment: `toggle` will change the visible state of elements, if it is hidden, it becomes visible, and vice versa. It does require you to have two `<img>` elements but it will save you from changing the source (as shown in @Riskbreaker answer). Do note that this is very different from changing an image source, though the visual effect is roughly the same.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i get it but doing it the attr would actually be slower than having the both images - The DOM has to work more...but your code is working ...Im just more into speed

Answer (score 0):

Grab the value of the src attribute and store it in a variable. Use this variable as your reference in an if statement to determine which image to switch to:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('.post-like').click(function(){
        var img=$(this).attr('src');
if(img=="img/like.jpg"){
 $(".post-like img").attr('src',"img/like.jpg");
       return false;
}else{
$(".post-like img").attr('src',"img/otherimage.jpg");
       return false;
}

     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

make it simpler and do **toggle**

```
$(".post-like").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

[**TOGGLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QAz2U/1331/)

Comment: nggg, when i type this its not work $(document).ready(function() { 
   $(".post-like").click(function() {
     $(this).find('.post-like img').toggle();
  });
  });

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with your code, it changed the source just fine.
In order to create a 'click to toggle'-flow, you need to know both sources, I tend to do this by having two variables (one with the 'special' source and one empty, which is set on first use).

```js
$(function() { 
    var specialSrc = 'http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nightlife-q-g-160-100-10.jpg',
        img = $('.post-like img'),
        normalSrc;

    $('.post-like').click(function(){
        var src = img.attr('src');
      
        if (!normalSrc) {
          normalSrc = src;
        }
        img.attr('src', src === normalSrc ? specialSrc : normalSrc);

      return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.post-like{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.post-like img{
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-like m-30">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nightlife-q-c-160-100-4.jpg" alt="">
  <h4 class="bold text-center capital">appreciate this!</h4>
</div><!-- post-like -->
```

I've also stored the image in the `img` variable, so you don't need to look for it every click, and I've replace `$(document).ready(function() {..})` with the shorter syntax `$(function() {..})` which does the same thing)